# django template filters change order of evaluation

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is there a way to change the order django evaluates a template filter ?

Say i have

```
{{ 3|add:5|multiply:"10" }}
```

Right now his adds 3+5 and multiplies the result times 10.

What i am looking for is a way of doing the following:

```
{{ 3|add:(5|multiply:"10") }}
```

As you can see i wrapped the `5|multiply:"10"` in parenthesis to emphasize that it should be evaluated before the `|add`. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

You could change the order of filters/values:

```
{{ 5|multiply:10|add:3 }}
```

Or You could use `{% with %}`:

```
{% with temp=5|multiply:10 %}
    {{ 3|add:temp }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Wow, never considered changing the order myself. Thanks :)